# What is causing my UI Thread to be blocked?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, event-handling, thread-safety

I am completely lost in what is really causing the problem. So rather trying to explain the problem, I might as well as get straight to the code with the problem. Here is the layout of my program:

```
    private void connection_OnMessage(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg)
    {     
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg.Body) && ((msg.XDelay != null && msg.XDelay.Stamp.Date == DateTime.Today) || msg.XDelay == null))
        {
            agsXMPP.Jid JID = new Jid(msg.From.Bare);

            int rowIndex = chatLog.Rows.Add();
            chatLog.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["chatNameColumn"].Value = JID.User;
            chatLog.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["chatMessageColumn"].Value = msg.Body;

            //Begin line of the problem
            if (IncomingMessage != null)
                IncomingMessage(this, JID.User, msg.Body);
            //End of the problem
        }
    }
```

The above code snippet is of class A. After starting up the program, this class makes the connection to the server. Right after being connected, this code snippet is rapidly fired about 20 times, once per line of message. (There are already about 20 lines of message in the chat log.) Since only one message makes it through the if condition, the lines commented with the problem is only run once. Those lines fire the code snippet below of class B.

(Around the time class A is firing, I have another class like A that fires the similar event to be handled by class B the same way, which will be handled by class C.)

```
    private void newSource_IncomingMessage(IChatSource sender, string user, string message)
    {
        UpdatedMessageEventHandler temp = UpdatedMessage;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(sender, user, message);
    }
```

The above code snippet of class B fires the code snippet below of class C.

```
    private void chatManager_UpdatedMessage(IChatSource source, string user, string message)
    {
        if (!source.Muted)
        {
            updateMessage(source, user, message);
        }            
    }

    delegate void UpdateMessageCallback(IChatSource source, string user, string message);

    private void updateMessage(IChatSource source, string user, string message)
    {
        if (allDataGridView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            UpdateMessageCallback d = new UpdateMessageCallback(updateMessage);
            Invoke(d, new object[] { source, user, message });
        }
        else
        {
            int row = allDataGridView.Rows.Add();
            allDataGridView.Rows[row].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = source.TextColor;
            allDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells["NameColumn"].Value = user;
            allDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells["MessageColumn"].Value = message;

            if (!MenuItem.Checked)
            {
                MenuItem.Checked = true;
                Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what I tried to do to fix the problem, but the code is removed already:

1. I tried adding lock to certain codes.
2. I tried to put the certain codes on a separate thread and have them run.

Here is what happened:

1. When I run the program, the UI thread seems to be blocked. In other words, class C doesn't get painted. Sometimes, the form doesn't even appear.
2. A few times, it complaint about a strange error "An error occurred invoking the method. The destination thread no longer exists."
3. If I commented out the problem lines, everything work fine, but here is the strange part. If I create a timer object in class A and have it fired the event the same way, it works fine.
4. While line stepping in debug mode, I sometimes got it work fine, but majority of the time, it fails.
5. For a few times, I run into InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." even though I did make it thread safe.

In conclusion, I don't know what is causing the UI thread to be blocked. Any pointer or what I might do wrong?

Comment: It seems that the `connection_OnMessage` is called from another thread. **Can you show the initialization of the connection?** Is there something that the `connection.connect` is blocking the gui thread? So the invoke will cause to hang.

Comment: When you run this with the debugger and the UI thread blocks, you can pause the process and look what threads are running at that time and what they are doing. Can you show what happens? The UI thread should be waiting for some call to return and it would probably be helpful to know which call that is.

Comment: And in `updateMessage` you check for `allDataGridView.InvokeRequired` but call `Invoke` on `this` instead of `allDataGridView`. This is probalby irrelevant, just to be sure all your controls are on one thread. btw: Maybe `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` could help too, but at first we should find out why this is hanging.

Comment: And what exactly do mean by _"4. .... but majority of the time, it fails"_ Fails how?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, connection_OnMessage is an event handler that is triggered when there is a message from the connection. It is initialized below: `connection.Open(); connection.OnLogin += new ObjectHandler(connection_OnLogin); connection.OnError += new ErrorHandler(connection_OnError); connection.OnMessage += new agsXMPP.protocol.client.MessageHandler(connection_OnMessage);`

Comment: @RenéVogt, I didn't know you can see which thread is running in debugger. Let me see what thread is causing the problem. At least, I see a race problem for modifying allDataGridView.

Comment: @QueTrac It is wise to bind the events before opening the connection, but this has nothing to do with your problem. The problem with the error _"Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."_ message is because of this: `chatLog.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["chatNameColumn"].Value = JID.User;` this should be invoked on the gui thread.

Comment: @RenéVogt, "4. ...it fails" means that it fails to unblock the UI thread. Anyway, I think I am getting close to the problem. I noticed that if I force the form to show() before the connection_OnMessage is fired, it works fine. Comparing the difference of the two scenarios, I noticed that the ownership of the UI is reversed. If the form is shown before, the ownership of the UI is the main thread, but if the form is shown after when the worker thread invokes show(), the ownership of the UI is the worker thread; thus, in this case, I run into InvalidOperationException for the main thread.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, I didn't run into Control accessed problem there. I run into it in class C for allDataGridView. `chatLog.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["chatNameColumn"]` is for class A, which is an UserControl that is added onto class C GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling methods crossthreading. This can lead to deadlocks.

You could solve this, adding the messages on a concurrent queue and on a timer (gui thread) checking the queue and adding the messages to controls.

*This is not a complete solution, but a method to prevent crossthread method invoking*

Like:  **(PSEUDO)**   (wrote online on the site)

```
// dataholder
public class ChatMsg
{
    public string User {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}

// message store
private List<ChatMsg> _messages = new List<ChatMsg>();
// timer
private Timer _timer;

// callback for you chatapi?? (like you wrote)
private void newSource_IncomingMessage(IChatSource sender, string user, string message)
{
    UpdatedMessageEventHandler temp = UpdatedMessage;

    // lock the store
    lock(_messages)
        _messages.Add(new ChatMsg { User = user, Message = message });
}

// constructor
public Form1()
{
    // create the check timer.
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 100;
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    _timer.Start();
}

// timer method
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // copy of the queue
    ChatMsg[] msgs;

    // lock the store and 'move' the messages
    lock(_messages)
    {
        msgs = _messages.ToArray();
        _messages.Clear();
    }

    if(msgs.Length == 0)
        return;

    // add them to the controls
    foreach(var msg in msgs)
    {
        // add the message to the gui controls... (copied from your question)
        int row = allDataGridView.Rows.Add();
        allDataGridView.Rows[row].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = source.TextColor;
        allDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells["NameColumn"].Value = user;
        allDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells["MessageColumn"].Value = message;
   }
}
```

---

Something like that..